# How to highlighted the selected row from repeater?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater, and i just want that when i select or click on any row of it then that would be highlighted. I had tried some code of javascript which makes the selected row highlighted, but not unhighlighting when select any other row.My code is:-

```
<tr id="gh" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="Select(this);">
```

any javascript's and style's code is:-

```
<style type="text/css">
    .highlight
    {
        background-color: Red;
    }
    .selected
    {
        background-color: #ffdc87;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Select(obj) {
        obj.className = 'selected';
        var tbl = document.getElementById("Repaddressorbbl")
        var firstRow = tbl.getElementsByTagName("TR")[0];
        var tableRowId = tbl.rows[firstRow.getElementById("gh").parentNode.id];
        alert(tableRowId);
        var oldRow = tbl.rows[firstRow.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0].value];
        if (oldRow != null) {
            oldRow.className = '';
        }
        firstRow.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0].value = obj.rowIndex;

    }

</script>
```

We can do it simply with code behind but the matter is it should be done only with jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use code similar to this:

```
var INDEX = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
$('#Repaddressorbbl tr:nth-child(' + INDEX + ')').addClass("highlight") 
                        .siblings()
                        .removeClass("highlight");  // remove css class from other rows
```

It gets the rownumber of the TR and adds a CSS class while removing the same class from all other TRs.

Comment: Why do you need the index? Can't you just say `$(this).addClass("highlight").siblings().removeClass("highlight");` and if `this` is the `tr` you can get the index directly without jQuery by saying `this.rowIndex`. (By the way, the question wasn't tagged with jQuery.)

Comment: You're right, you don't really need the index. And although the question wasn't tagged accordingly, this does provide an easy solution to the problem at hand, so the OP might want to use it or isn't aware of jQuery's powers.

Comment: Well that seems to have worked: the question has been updated to include jQuery. I hope you don't mind, but I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Update for jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("tr").click(function() {
      $(this).addClass("highlight").siblings().removeClass("highlight");
   }
}
```

Original answer:

If I understand you correctly, all of your table rows are defined like this:

```
<tr id="gh" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="Select(this);">
```

And you want to set a class on the most recently clicked row so it looks selected, while clearing said class from the previously clicked/selected row?

If so, a much simplified version of your function should do it:

```
var selectedRow = null;

function Select(obj) {
   if (obj != selectedRow) {
      if (selectedRow != null) {
         selectedRow.className = '';
      }
      obj.className = 'selected';
      selectedRow = obj;
   }
}
```

I don't understand what you're trying to do with the `firstRow.getElementsByTagName("tr")` stuff. Have you got nested tables?

Comment: actually There are number of table visible conditionally.Sir your code is not working its selecting every row on which i m clicking. but not removing the class..

Comment: OK, sorry, but perhaps you could've made it clear in your question that there are multiple tables. Are the tables nested? Please show some more html. Is your intention that each table have its own, independent highlighting? If so my jQuery version should do that already. If you only want highlighting in one table then change the "tr" selector to be "#id_of_table tr". As far as the non-jQuery version, I'm not going to suggest a change to it until I understand how you want the multiple tables to work.

Answer (score 0):

i've added a function to select elements with a specific classname so you can easly search the dom for elements with that class

```
onload=function(){
    if (document.getElementsByClassName == undefined) {
        document.getElementsByClassName = function(className)
        {
            var hasClassName = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + className + "(?:$|\\s)");
            var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
            var results = [];

            var element;
            for (var i = 0; (element = allElements[i]) != null; i++) {
                var elementClass = element.className;
                if (elementClass && elementClass.indexOf(className) != -1 && hasClassName.test(elementClass))
                    results.push(element);
            }

            return results;
        }
    }
}
function Select(obj) {
    var oldRow = document.getElementsByClassName('selected');
    if(oldRow.length > 0)
        oldRow[0].className = '';
    obj.className = 'selected';
}
```